# ImageView inside ListView and bitmap not fully displayed

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I'm having issues with a ListView containing an ImageView, it works fine on tablets but not on my phone...

Here is the expected output (on my tablet):
[image]

And here is the actual output (on my phone):
[image]

I tried using a drawable, it works well on my phone.
Here is how I create the Bitmap and bind it to the view :

```
Bitmap srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.portrait);
Bitmap modBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp,0,0,60,60);
((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(thebmp);
```

My row layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60px"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:id="@+id/charIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/blason" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/charName"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I really don't understand why it does this...
I'm quite new to android but this is really weird

EDIT : the blason is only in my drawable folder, and its size is 60x60 pixels

EDIT2 : I'm using this Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp,0,0,60,60); as I need only this portion of the image (the whole head should be shown). Here is a part of portrait.png :
[image]

Comment: You are using **px**. Try using **dp**. It will scale better.

Comment: If you have the image in your drawable folder and its of the perfect dimensions then Why not just set using `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blason);`

Comment: dp/px isn't the issue here it seems. On my tablet the whole head is shown, not on the phone, whatever dimensions I use for the ImageView

Comment: @Shivam_Verma : the blason resource is simply a default image in case I later can't find the good character to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap.createBitmap will use the source of the bitmap and will give you a cut of that. Just what you see in your results.

Try using:
[createScaled bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) instead.

**Edit:**
If you do nothing, the imageView will scalle it for you. So best solution will be just removing the new bitmap line:

```
Bitmap srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.portrait);
//Bitmap modBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp,0,0,60,60);
((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(thebmp);
```

And add the scale mode in the xml like @blipinsk suggested.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

**Edit 2:** Try changing the LinearLayout to WrapContent, the parent might be smaller than 60px

**Edit 3:** `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` will decode in the device density unless you pass an options setting that says, use the true size. So this is probably what you want to do, since you are working with pixels.

Comment: That's exactly my purpose to cut the 60x60 first pixels :/ I have a sort of spriteshits with different character heads, and I need to get only one of those, that's why I cut it. The scaleType doesn't fix it as I answered to blipinsk

Comment: @Lectem So what is wrong with the result? It looks cut to me.

Comment: The difference seems pretty clear between the tablet and my phone, on the tablet it's cut correctly (you see the whole head) while on the phone you see only a part of it

Comment: I did try to use 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
But it's not working either

Comment: @Lectem Than it can be only one thing. You are not using the same image

Comment: I just figured out that cutting at 1.5*60 for the phone did the trick, then I checked the density of the bitmap, and it wasn't the same (though I have only one file, and it is in the drawable folder).
I'm now looking for a way to set the density of the source so that I will always have the same output on all the devices

Comment: @Lectem yeah this is it. Just make sure to work with options and real size as I suggested in edit 3

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the edit as I was writing the answer.
The decodeResource is indeed tricky.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to your imageview

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer !
The BitmapFactory.decodeResource will scale the png according to the device pixel density, even if you don't provide different versions of the image.
You can disable the scaling like this

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opt=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inScaled=false;
    srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rcontext.getResources(), R.drawable.portrait, opt);
```

This way I always get the real portion of the source image, in terms of pixels.